# "Suggested Edits" page style seems broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The text is the same color as the background, and the background isn't consistent with the rest of the /review pages.

Related, the "suggested edit count" box at the top (not shown) is just a solid orange square.

[image: suggested edits page]

Comment: we're working on a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix has been deployed. Please verify.